# cant able to upload media to my wordpress blog

Tags: media, uploads

i am trying to upload an image for a post in my [WordPress blog](http://examtimetable.net/) but it is giving error:

> “image.gif” has failed to upload.
>   Unable to create directory uploads/2016/02. Is its parent directory writable by the server?.

kindly anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Double check if the `uploads` directory exists and writable (permission sets to **775**)

Comment: See [changing file permissions on codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions). That will provide further guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the permissions on the uploads folder to 777 via ftp worked.
or contact with your domain server for the problem, may max upload size is limited